# Flopy error: Cannot find gridgen binary executable

Tags: spyder, windows-11, flopy

Trying to call gridgen executable file using below codes:

```
# use of gridgen   # https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/blob/5fcf9709ec8a655106c57d55657c47b1d4987812/examples/Notebooks/flopy3_gridgen.ipynb
# setup the active domain
    from flopy.utils.gridgen import Gridgen 
# Check and make sure the data folder exists.
    
if not os.path.exists(model_ws):
        os.makedirs(model_ws)
    gridgen_ws = os.path.join(model_ws, 'gridgen')
    if not os.path.exists(gridgen_ws):
        os.makedirs(gridgen_ws)
    print('Model workspace is : {}'.format(model_ws))
    print('Gridgen workspace is : {}'.format(gridgen_ws))

 # **Getting an error while executing below code**
    g = Gridgen(dis, model_ws=gridgen_ws)
```

Error: raise Exception("Cannot find gridgen binary executable")
Exception: Cannot find gridgen binary executable

Copied the code from:  https://github.com/chenmingzhang/ewatering/blob/main/modflow_planar_2D/ewatering_mf6_jupytext.py.
From line 504 to 516 & line 541.
I have downloaded [GRIDGEN](https://water.usgs.gov/water-resources/software/GRIDGEN/gridgen.1.0.02.zip) to the indicated folder, then tried changing paths names, replacing all kinds of slashes, but can't resolve the issue.
Followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDAkmN4vy4Q&t=3435s), but there isn't much explained about gridgen
So, please help..

Comment: Also followed this link : https://github.com/modflowpy/flopy/blob/5fcf9709ec8a655106c57d55657c47b1d4987812/examples/Notebooks/flopy3_gridgen.ipynb. At In[2] I copied the same code and got an "else" output, but at In[6] I am having same error as in post.

Comment: Hello, have you unzipped the Gridgen folder?